# How to add a timer to keep check for 500 error message untill it changes to a different message using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to  keep checking for 500 error server message  and until the success message is  200 and i want it to time out after 2mins and give some message

How can i do it codingly?

here is my code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "some.json",
            statusCode: {
                500: function() {
                    alert(" 500  lower data still loading");
                    console.log('500 ');
                }
            }
        }); 


    });
```

Comment: There's no recursion here, just put it in a `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I imagine, using `setTimeout`:

```
var timesChecked = 0;
function checkForMessage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "some.json",
        statusCode: {
            500: function() {
                if(timesChecked < 240) {
                    alert("500  lower data still loading");
                    console.log('500 ');
                    setTimeout(checkForMessage, 500);
                    timesChecked++;
                } else {
                    alert("Request timed out...");
                }
            },
            200: function() {
                alert("200! Data has loaded.");
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Of course, `setInterval` works as well.

Comment: I wrapped around your code with my code, when i do that it doesn't seem to execute on 500